# ios15 UITableView Section Label font size and color was change

Tags: uitableview, ios15, sectionheader

After upgrading ios14 to ios15, the font size and color of the label in the section of uitableview have changed.

[click link view picture!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l8LGD.png)

Is there any global solution.

My current method is like this, but I can only solve one tableview

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayHeaderView:(UIView *)view forSection:(NSInteger)section {
    UITableViewHeaderFooterView *header = (UITableViewHeaderFooterView *)view;
    header.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.137f green:0.137f blue:0.137f alpha:1.0];
    header.textLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:17]; 


   NSLog(@"title size is %f",header.textLabel.font.pointSize);
}
```

LOG:
IOS14: title size is 17.000000
IOS15: title size is 15.000000